# How to compare values of NSDictionary with String

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary

I have two `orgunit_id`'s, `test["orgunit_id"]` and `API.loginManagerInfo.orgUnit`, which I would like to compare. The problem is that the variables have different types. `test["orgunit_id"]` is value of a `NSDictionary` and the other one is a String. 
I've tried several ways to cast it into Integers, but without success.

**Code:**

```
if(!orgUnits.isEmpty){
    print(orgUnits) //See at console-output

    for test: NSDictionary in orgUnits {

        println(test["orgunit_id"]) //See at console-output
        println(API.loginManagerInfo.orgUnit) //See at console-output

        if(Int(test["orgunit_id"]? as NSNumber) == API.loginManagerInfo.orgUnit?.toInt()){ // This condition fails
                ...
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[{
    name = Alle;
    "orgunit_id" = "-1";
    shortdescription = Alle;
}, {
    name = "IT-Test";
    "orgunit_id" = 1;
    shortdescription = "";
}]
Optional(-1)
Optional("-1")
```

Edit:
Here's the definition of `API.loginManagerInfo.orgUnit`: `var orgUnit:String?`

Answer (score 0):

Use `if let` to safely unwrap your values *and* typecast the result.

If `test["orgunit_id"]` is an Optional Int and if `API.loginManagerInfo.orgUnit` is an Optional String:

```
if let testID = test["orgunit_id"] as? Int, let apiIDString = API.loginManagerInfo.orgUnit, let apiID =  Int(apiIDString) {
    if testID == apiID {
        // ...
    }    
}
```

You *may* have to adapt this example given what is in your dictionary, but you get the point: safely unwrap the optional value and either typecast it (with `if let ... = ... as? ...`) or transform it (with `Int(...)`) before comparing.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. I got the following compile error:  `Variable with getter/setter cannot have an initial value`

Comment: Okay, This brings up more error messages. First: `'let' cannot appear nested inside another 'var' oder 'let' pattern` and Second: `variable used within its own initial value`.

Comment: There's no `let` nested inside a `var` in my example. This error comes from something specific in your code that we don't know of. Also, make sure to use at least Swift 1.2, not an older version! Otherwise the multiple `if let` won't work indeed.